# Swift Generators: What is the counterpart to next()?

Tags: string, swift, iterator, generator

I am currently learning Swift. While playing around with Generators I came across the following problem: **Given a generator `iter`. How do I go back one item?**

For example:

```
var str = "Hello World"
var iter = str.characters.generate()

iter.next() // => H
...
iter.next() // => l
iter.next() // => o


// how can I get this functionality to go back? 
iter.previous() => l
iter.next() => o
```

*If not using generators: How can I get this behaviour to go forward and backward (in a String)?*

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use index:

```
var str = "Hello World"

let i0 = str.startIndex
let i1 = i0.successor()
let i00 = i1.predecessor()

str[i0] // H
str[i1] // e
str[i00] // H
```

Comment: Wow. That was fast. Thanks!